# Why can't I style my drop downs?

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS.  I am doing a project where I need two drop down menus side by side.  I would like to be able to style them with size ,color and so on.  I am trying to create a selector and style them but I keep getting nowhere. Please help!! Here is my code thus far.

```css
.mydropdown1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size:1em; 
  font-family: Arial
}
```

```html
<p> (Job Openings 000) </p>

<select class="mydropdown1">
    <option value="language" selected>Language</option>
    <option value="english">English</option>
    <option value="french">French</option>
    <option value="german">German</option>
    <option value="italian">Italian</option>
    <option value="dutch">Dutch</option>
    <option value="spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>
  
<select class="mydropdown2">
    <option value="job ategories" selected> Job Categories</option>
    <option value="writer">Writer</option>
    <option value="editor">Editor</option>
    <option value="artist">Artist</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Converted to snippet. It seems to work just fine. There's gotta be a problem in the way you link your css or include it in the file.

Answer (score -3):

style not work in select

create custom dropdown
https://select2.github.io/examples.html with this

Comment: i am give only her an example, how to style a dropdown. because she is new in HTML and CSS.